# Load yaml parameters conditionally in python launch file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use a launch parameter to decide whether to load a yaml file, or chose which yaml to load if I have many configuration

For example in ROS1 it would be possible to write something like this:

```
<arg name="load_config_X" default="true"/>
<arg name="config_type" default="config_A"/>    

<node ...>
    <rosparam if="$(eval arg('load_config_X') == True)" command="load" file="..." />
    <rosparam if="$(eval arg('config_type') == 'config_A') " command="load" file="..." />
    <rosparam if="$(eval arg('config_type') == 'config_B') " command="load" file="..." />
</node>
```

Is there any equivalent to this in ROS2 python files?

```
load_config_X = DeclareLaunchArgument("load_config_X", default_value=False)
config_type = DeclareLaunchArgument("config_type", default_value='config_A')

my_node = Node(
    package='my_pkg',
    name='my_node',
    executable='my_node',
    parameters=[
         # ???
         # os.path.join('path', 'to', 'config_X.yaml'),
         # os.path.join('path', 'to', 'config_A.yaml'),
    ]
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402709/load-yaml-parameters-conditionally-in-python-launch-file/) by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2022-06-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found my way in the `launch/launch_ros` source code:

For example it is possible to switch between 2 configs A/B with `SetLaunchConfiguration` like this:

```
launch_configuration.append(SetLaunchConfiguration("yaml_config", "config_A.yaml", condition=UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration("some_option"))))
launch_configuration.append(SetLaunchConfiguration("yaml_config", "config_B.yaml", condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration("some_option"))))

my_node = Node(
    package='my_pkg',
    name='my_node',
    executable='my_node',
    parameters=[
        PathJoinSubstitution([FindPackageShare('my_pkg'), 'config', LaunchConfiguration('yaml_config')])
    ]
)
```

There is also `LaunchConfigurationEquals` for non boolean tests:

```
condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfigurationEquals("config_type", "config_A"))
```

And to trigger loading with a bool, the full path could be set into a `SetLaunchConfiguration` like this:

```
launch_configuration.append(SetLaunchConfiguration("yaml_config",  PathJoinSubstitution([FindPackageShare('my_pkg'), 'config', 'config_X.yaml'), condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration("load_config_X"))))
# ...
my_node = Node(
    # ...
    parameters=[
        LaunchConfiguration('yaml_config'),
    ]
)
```

At the end of the day, it was not complicated, unfortunately the launch api is not documented yet :(

---

Originally posted by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) with karma: 108 on 2022-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) on 2022-06-23**:
Although it works, the solution is quickly cumbersome. A better approach is to use `OpaqueFunction` like [here](https://github.com/Serafadam/interbotix_ros_manipulators/blob/xsarm_control_galactic/interbotix_ros_xsarms/interbotix_xsarm_control/launch/xsarm_control.launch.py) and `.perform(context)` to evaluate parameters value directly in the script